# Debugger issue in VS Code with Firefox. Breakpoints isn`t working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, firefox

I had common angular project that was generated just now (`ng new my-app`). I have added configuration in my `launch.json` look up below:

```
{
"name": "Debug Firefox", 
"type": "firefox", 
"request": "launch", 
"reAttach": true, 
"url": "http://localhost:4200", 
"preLaunchTask": "npm: start", 
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}" 
},
```

For testing i used the next code in my `app.component.ts`:

```
public GetConsoleLog(): void {
    console.log("it`s fine"); // first breakpoint here
    console.log("it`s fine second time"); // the second breakpoint 
  }
```

Whenever i tried to using breakpoints in firefox it was ignored. i don`t know why.

Honestly, I do not use `"start-debugging-firefox"` for running debug because it does not work (it has infinity loading in VS Code). Because these launch settings already running the application in separately window with debugging mode.

A few hints about:

- `sourceMap` has `true`,
- firefox debug for vs code has installed,
- debug in **chrome** actually works,
- yep, i used `"firefox -start-debugger-server"`**,**
- `"about:config"` was configured.